# Session lost after window.location.href

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

In login html page(my html in m.yazilimsozluk.com sub domain) I make ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mobile.yazilimsozluk.com/Account/Login/",
        .....
```

In Account controller Login action I set User session

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  .....
  Session["MemberId"] = Member.ID;
  ....
}
```

and then in profile.htm page(my html in m.yazilimsozluk.com sub domain)
I make ajax call if user is login like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mobile.yazilimsozluk.com/Uye/IsAccount/",
        ...
```

but in Uye controller IsAccount action session(Session["MemberId"]) is null always

```
public JsonResult IsAccount()
{

   if (Session["MemberId"] != null)
}
```

why session is lost?in user.htm I make call it set session ,there is no problem

but in profile.htm when ajax call go action session is null

there is no any attribute about session in global.asax or web.config

you can login here :http://m.yazilimsozluk.com/user.htm  ( username and pass is Tanebaum ) after login in hamburger clikc profilim :http://m.yazilimsozluk.com/profile.htm

Comment: try HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: @REDEVI_    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MemberId"] = GirisYapanId.FirstOrDefault();  I set like this  and control like this although it set it it is still null after ajax call  if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MemberId"] != null)

Comment: change you http to GET

Comment: I change post to get but it still does not work